# How to retrieve a phone number for a gprs request in a j2me application?

Tags: java-me

I am creating an j2me application in which for activation user sends a GPRS request request. Can we get the user phone number with his GPRS request?

Comment: via sending GPRS request for activation we would like to attach users phone number with the request.

Comment: Can we know the users phone number via any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, I mean up to MIDP2, I don't know about MIDP3 yet. 
You must think of different mechanism to get the phone number, for instance is sending SMS via the application to Server SMS Gateway, 
The mechanism goes like this :
- Your application send SMS to Server SMS gateway
- Server generate some random number and then save this random number to phone number match in database. 
- And then SMS Gateway send SMS reply which contain the random number to the application. 
- Your application retrieve the content of the SMS (which is the server generated random number) and save it to local DB. 
- After this everytime you send any request (HTTP request) you send also the random number you have saved.

Therefore in the server you can find out which phone send the request.